# Bash: grep command for divide a line between ":" and showing the third part

Tags: bash, sed, grep, cut

The script read a file by argument.

Then the script will ask for the two cities, **origin_city** and **destiny_city** from which we want to get their distance.

Once introduced, it will search if there is any
line **origin_city:destiny_city:distance** in the file of the distances

If found, it will show the distance, if not, it will report it.

Example:

```
Show distance between cities

Intro origin_city: Barcelona (we input it / read it)

Intro destiny_city: Madrid (we input it / read it) 

Distance: 623 Km
```

The file format is:

```
Barcelona:Valencia:350
Barcelona:Madrid:623
Valencia:Zaragoza:308
Madrid:Lugo:505
Barcelona:Sevilla:995
```

So, I know I need to use **grep** here and probably **sed** and **cut**, but don't know how, so I'm asking for your help. I have this but don't work:

```
grep origen:desti
if [ "$origen" == $(cut -d":" -f1) ]
then
    echo "1"
else    
    echo "0"
fi
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
origin=Barcelona
destination=Madrid
distance=$(awk -F: -vf=$origin -vt=$destination '$1==f && $2==t{print $3}' file)
if [[ $distance ]]; then
    echo "$origin => $destination: $distance"
else
    echo >&2 "no match"
fi
```

#### Output

```
623
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, this has worked perfectly :)